# ON MacBook M1 when adding pod file to the flutter project using "arch -x86_64 pod install" it take forever to install

Tags: flutter, firebase, cocoapods, apple-m1

I'm Developing a flutter project and using firebase. but when ever I add firebase dependencies e.g cloud_firestone, firebase_auth, firebase_core, stored_preferences and use command "arch -x86_64 pod install" to add pod dependencies it take forever to add it. Is there any faster way to add them

Comment: Why are you use Rosetta emulator to do this?

Comment: is there a reason you are having the system emulate Intel on Apple Silicon?

Comment: I'm not even sure if I'm using a Rosetta emulator or not..

Comment: arch -x86_64 says "Rosetta, please run this code for me"